# Excel formula to lookup one value, then search the cells within that row to see if any contain specific text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am needing to write a formula to first search for a specific number within a column, and then search the cells within that row to see if any cells contain some specific text (cell reference).
[image]

In this scenario, the first criteria is finding the number in S2 within Column B, and then looking for the text in S3 within the range of D3:J9, but only returning a value if the text is within the specific row of the number from S2.

```
=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(1,($B$3:$B$9=$S2)*(D$3:D$9=$S$3),$Q$3:$Q$9),"Not Found")
```

I wrote this that works, but only searches one column at a time from the D3:J9 range, so is not efficient with large data sets. Looking to have a single formula that can search the whole range once the specific number in column B is found.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is your expected result? "Yes" if found _anywhere_ in D:J for specific row? Or per each column D:J a "Yes" or "not found"?

Comment: I would be looking to use index() with two match() functions - one for the row and one for the column, but without data to test with it's just a suggestion.

Comment: @Ike just returning Yes if found anywhere in D:J for specific row

Comment: So you want it to return TRUE and FALSE values if the value in S3 is found within the row S2 is?

Comment: @KevinP. honestly just looking for a simple "yes" if the S3 value is found anywhere in the row, and "no" if not found. Don't need a separate return for each column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a go with something along these lines:

[image]

Formula in `M5`:

```
=IF(OR(XLOOKUP(M2,B2:B8,C2:J8,"")=M3),"Yes","No")
```

---

If you need an output per row, then try:

[image]

Formula in `K2`:

```
=IF(BYROW((B2:B8=M2)*(C2:J8=M3),OR),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: I think the notation of BYROW/OR is still in Beta, but love it!

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood correctly, not mistaken then OP needs the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>Q3</kbd>

```
=IF((S2=B3:B9)*BYROW(D3:J9,LAMBDA(x,OR(x=S3))),"Yes","Not Found")
```

---

Or, without <kbd>LAMBDA()</kbd> helper functions:

[image]

---

```
=IF(MMULT((D3:J9=S3)*(B3:B9=S2),SEQUENCE(7)^0),"Yes","Not Found")
```

---